# Edit a variable from list (Cannot use dictionary)

Tags: python, list, variables

```
a = 10
b = 20
ls = [a, b]
```

How do I change the variable a to e.g. 20 using `ls[0]` as a parameter?

I remember there is some way to write code where you could input string and variables and it would turn into a line of code and run it.

This is how I faintly remember it, something like:

```
run(ls[0], "= 20")
```

Showing the whole code, instead of a condensed version, what I am trying to do is load and save variables from a text file. (Code is for a terminal game about making drugs.)

```
money = 11000

growtime = 45
growreward = 50
gramsweed = 0
growing = False

pots = 1
seeds = 0

cooktime = 90
cookreward = 20
gramsmeth = 0
cooking = False

tanks = 0
methlitres = 0

weedselling = 0
methselling = 0
currentlyselling = False

dealers = 1
dealtime = 120
dealamount = 15

stats = [money, growtime, growreward, gramsweed, growing, pots, seeds, cooktime,
         cookreward, gramsmeth, cooking, tanks, methlitres, weedselling, methselling,
         currentlyselling, dealers, dealtime, dealamount]

boolstats = [growing, cooking, currentlyselling]

def save():
    f = open("save.txt", "w")
    for stat in stats:
        f.write(str(stat) + "\n")
    f.close()
    mainmenu()

def load():
    i = 0
    f = open("save.txt", "r")
    for stat in stats:
        print(stat)
        stats[i] = f.readline(i)
        i += 1
    j = 0
    for stat in boolstats:
        if stat == "False": boolstats[j] = False
        else: boolstats[j] = True
        j += 1
    f.close()
    mainmenu()
```

Comment: Not possible: `[a, b]` immediately creates the list `[10, 20]` which has no idea where these numbers came from.

Comment: I know the title of your question says "cannot use dictionary", but use a dictionary anyway.  Technically every variable is a dictionary entry anyway so you can't avoid it even if you aren't creating a dictionary directly.

Comment: @ForceBru True, brain fart on my end. Would this somehow work with a separate list with names of all the variables? I could use a dictionary but id have to edit every variable to have ```list["variable"]```. this would probably be what you would do in a professional setting but this is just an amateur at home project.

Comment: @Gabbisen If you provide a bit more context on what you're trying to do in your project, I'm confident that somebody will be able to suggest a very straightforward solution.  Anything you can do with crazy dynamic variable stuff can be done *much more easily* with a dictionary.

Comment: @ForceBru Ive added the complete bit of code, probably easier to help that way.

Comment: Never name your variable `list`! That is a reserved keyword and you're bound to get unexpected behavior.

Comment: @NathanielFord aha I didn't really, just for the example. I've got the full code there if you wanna take a look (and possible help)

Comment: It would be a bit easier to understand where your problem is if you were to provide sample input, and what your expected output is, as well as what output you're actually seeing. It does seem like you want a dictionary. (Nothing in your actual code seems to map well onto your condensed example)

Comment: @NathanielFord It would probably be easier with a dictionary, but id have to edit every variable in the code for it to work right? Wanted to find an easier solution but at this point I should probably just bite the bullet and to the work.

Comment: You will need to do a little refactoring of existing code if you switch around how the data is stored, but all the code you write from that point forward will be a lot easier if you do that refactoring now!  The longer you keep a bad design pattern, the harder it gets to extend the code, and eventually you end up having to throw the whole thing away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how to store your game data in a dict and use the `json` module to easily save/load it.  I'm going to start by just putting all of your variable declarations into a dict (note that I would normally use the `{}` syntax instead of the `dict()` constructor, but I'm copying and pasting your existing code and this makes it slightly easier):

```
stats = dict(
    money = 11000,

    growtime = 45,
    growreward = 50,
    gramsweed = 0,
    growing = False,

    pots = 1,
    seeds = 0,

    cooktime = 90,
    cookreward = 20,
    gramsmeth = 0,
    cooking = False,

    tanks = 0,
    methlitres = 0,

    weedselling = 0,
    methselling = 0,
    currentlyselling = False,

    dealers = 1,
    dealtime = 120,
    dealamount = 15,
)
```

and now I can write your `save` and `load` functions in just a couple lines of code each:

```
import json

def save():
    with open("save.txt", "w") as f:
        json.dump(stats, f)

def load():
    with open("save.txt") as f:
        stats.update(json.load(f))
```

The `json` module takes care of reading the lines, parsing them, converting them to the right types, *all of it*, because it can just pull all the information it needs right out of the dictionary object.  You can't get that same type of convenience and flexibility if you have a dozen different individual variables.

To suggest the ways you'd convert the other pieces of your game code to use a dict instead of individual variables I'd need to see that code, but hopefully this one example helps convince you that life can be *much* easier if you don't need to deal with variables one at a time!

Comment: Thanks, ill be using this. Do you have any tips for adding the ```stats[""]```to every variable or will I have to do it manually?

Comment: Like I said, I really need to see the code.  Odds are good that a lot of the code you've written doesn't need explicit references to those variables *at all* and you can replace huge chunks of copy+pasted variable references with simple iterations.  Without seeing the code that's as much as I can help.

Answer (score -2):

It will not work as you desire since primitive types are passed by value. You can try:

```
globals()['a'] = 20 # works for global variables only, not local
```

or store your value in class variable, then it list will keep a reference to it.

Comment: In code provided you can use dict to store values.

Comment: I can't rightly recommend any path that includes globals. 9 out of a 10 times it's not the right way, and the 10th time it's a  disaster.

Comment: "since primitive types are passed by value." Python doesn't *have* primitive types, and nothing is *ever* passed by value (or by reference, for that matter). The evaluation strategy *never* depends on the type, because there is only one evaluation strategy.

Comment: You are right, Built-in numeric types are classes. If you add class instance to list you can modify it and see modification via other reference. Is it possible with <class 'int'>? Should one thing about <class 'int'> as immutable like <class 'str'>?